# How to efficiently read multiple images from documents directory in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance

I am working on an app that saves multiple images in Documents directory. These images can be up to 100. Now use following method to read the image from Documents directory. This method is called for all images in Documents directory.

```
UIImage *currentImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathOfFileInDocumentsDictory];
```

So in worse case this method will run for 100 images and I have checked using XCode that this method takes around 100 miliseconds. So this makes 10 seconds for 100 images if I am not wrong. I want to make it efficient. Is there any better way to read those image for efficiently and in less time?

Comment: What is the goal?  Less battery usage, shorter "clock" time, or more responsive UI?  If the latter, try loading in a background thread, and maybe even low-res thumbnails of the visible things first.  Thumbnails will increase overall time but may actually seem faster to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using run loops, you could do this:

```
-(void) loadInBackground {

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(_loadInBackground) withObject:nil];

}

-(void) _loadInBackground {

    // Do all your heavy loading here
    UIImage *currentImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathOfFileInDocumentsDictory];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadedImage:) withObject:currentImage waitUntilDone:YES];

}

-(void) loadedImage:(UIImage*)img {

    // Do something with the loaded image
    anImageView.image = img;

}
```

Comment: Thanks jjv360 for response but I dont think it will reduce the time of loading the images because images are still being loaded and there are 100 I/Os for 100 images. What I am looking for is to reduce number of I/Os to the file system. Do you think we can achieve this?

Comment: Not that I know of... But whatever you end up doing, you should do it on a background thread or else your app will freeze until it's done...

Comment: I suspect jjv360's solution might actually reduce the time since it will load multiple images simultaneously.  That means that the processing of image1 could happen at the same time as the I/O for image2.  With questions like these, though, the only way to know for sure is to try it.

Comment: +1 - you *definitely* need to do this kind of work in the background. Also, I'm not sure why you're so set on "reduc[ing] number of I/Os" - generally, if you have 100 files, that means 100 file reads. You could zip the files together, read the zip file (again in the background), unzip it, and create UIImages from the raw data, but that seems more error-prone and much more difficult. This answer is probably the best fit for your situation on iOS.

Comment: wow that I did not think about. Thank you so much jjv360 and samkass.I will get back to you guys after trying this out at my end.

Comment: Yes Tim and also liked the solution after I thought about it and read the samkass reply too. :-)